# How to automatically put a file as resolved after merge

Tags: git, windows-7, merge, tortoisegit, 3-way-merge

I started using TortoiseGit for Windows but I found some things annoying. For example when I have a conflict during a merge I need to do the following:

- do the 3 way merge (of course... there is no other choice)
- mark the file as resolved

Is there an automatic way of marking the file as resolved if the merge ends successfully?

Thanks for any pointers,

Iulian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to adjust your config to trust the exit code of your merge tool:

```
git config mergetool.<tool>.trustExitCode true
```

This assumes that the merge tool you use has an exit code that corresponds to whether or not the merge was successful or not.

Here is more info:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mergetool.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: It seems to be ok. I will try this out. Thanks!

Comment: The answer should be combined with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957630/how-do-you-merge-in-git-on-windows - with a mention:

This is not available from Tortoise, but only from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Well they are text files, source code. successfully is when the file works/compiles as you want it to be.

Comment: I don't want to do 2 separate operations. I want that once I have merged the file with meld/kdiff3 or similar tools to be marked as resolved.