# What's a good (free) visual merge tool for Git? (on windows)

Tags: windows, git, version-control, merge

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137102/whats-the-best-visual-merge-tool-for-git) was already asked, but for Ubuntu.

It would help to know if the tool is free as in beer or as in liber.

Also, up and downs of the tool would be nice to know.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

On Windows, a good 3-way diff/merge tool remains [kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) ([WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/), for now, is still 2-way based, pending WinMerge3)

See "[How do you merge in GIT on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957630/how-do-you-merge-in-git-on-windows)" and [this config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426026/git-on-windows-how-do-you-set-up-a-mergetool/5529569#5529569).

---

Update 7 years later (Aug. 2018): [Artur Kędzior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/275882/artur-k%C4%99dzior) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227826/whats-a-good-free-visual-merge-tool-for-git-on-windows/7227985?noredirect=1#comment90710467_7227985):

If you guys happen to use [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) (Community Edition is free), try the tool that is shipped with it: [`vsDiffMerge.exe`](https://gist.github.com/JunielKatarn/530005dd432e2bd4552c856d4f886cc7). It's really awesome and easy to use.

Comment: Depite favouring BC, I'm going to check this tool out.

Comment: @Preet: BC remains the best ;) But for a *free* tool (multi-platform at that), kdiff3 is not bad.

Comment: but it defintly isn't that good either :) I tend to find it easier to use my regular code editor.

Comment: @Warpzit I agree there is a bit of a learning curve, but I am used to it now ;)

Comment: Then run: git config --global merge.tool "kdiff3";
git config --global mergetool.kdiff3.path "C:\Program Files\KDiff3\kdiff3.exe"

Comment: winmerge looks ugly on high resolution screen and useless for merge. After I've removed line from the right file, I was unable used the tool having error message.

Comment: @user4674453 regarding the resolution, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/ssms-highdpi-support/ (replace ssms by winmerge name and path)

Comment: @VonC, not my job. I've chosen another tool instead.

Comment: @user4674453 OK. What did you choose on Windows? Beyond Compare?

Comment: @VonC, I've chosen Diffmerge from SourceGear. It is mentioned in one of answers.

Comment: If you guys happen to use Visual Studio (Community Edition is free) try tool that is shipped with it: `vsDiffMerge.exe`. It's really awesome and easy to use.

Comment: @ArturKędzior Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 84):

I've also used [Meld](https://meldmerge.org/). It's written in python. There is an official installer for Windows that works well.

Install it and then set it as your default mergetool.

```
$ git config --global merge.tool "meld"
$ git config --global mergetool.meld.path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Meld\Meld.exe"
```

If using a GUI GIT client, try the following (instructions for SourceTree, adjust accordingly)

- In SourceTree, go to Tools/Options/Diff
- In `External Diff Tool`, choose Custom
- Enter `C:\Program Files (x86)\Meld\meld.exe` in Diff Command and `$LOCAL $REMOTE` in Arguments
- In `Merge Tool`, choose Custom
- Enter `C:\Program Files (x86)\Meld\meld.exe` in Diff Command and `$LOCAL $MERGED $REMOTE` in Arguments

Comment: Thanks, Meld is really nice :) It's really clear and easy to see whats going on. Thanks for posting the install instructions. I would have been lost without those.

Comment: If you are using cygwin/babun, replace the 2nd option with: `git config --global mergetool.meld.path "/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Meld/Meld.exe"`

Comment: +1 for the git config, I used it with P4Merge below: `git config --global merge.tool "p4merge" && git config --global mergetool.p4merge.path "C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4merge.exe"`

Comment: @Gordolio, Is there a "simple" or "low resolution" UI for meld? The graphics is a bit *too* beautiful which totally chokes on huge files.

Comment: I tried Meld and it was good, with some nice visuals, but in the end went for Beyond Compare, with pay, and have been very happy. One minus of Meld is that the buttons don't give mouseover descriptions. Another - Beyond Compare provides buttons to move from one difference to the next. Another - Beyond Compare shows the file paths in the window title bars. Meld was certainly "Good enough", but I'd rather pay for Beyond Compare. (And I have no affiliation with Beyond Compare).

Comment: meld is too slow on windows, faster ones are: kdiff3, winmergeu

Comment: Nothing wrong with Meld, at least as a first diff tool to try, and very easy to download and install. Very nice gui. Bonus: is from the GNOME project. Better than the builtin difftool in VSCode, and nicer than what I was used to use in Tortoise SVN.

Answer (score 30):

I've been using [P4Merge](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce_visual_merge_and_diff_tools), it's free and cross platform.

[image: P4Merge]

Comment: Is this still free?  It doesn't appear to be free at all.

Comment: Yes, still 100% free, but their download page hides it a little.

Comment: It is free as Daniel said but when you run the installer, you need to disable all of the options except the "Visual Merge Tool".  Otherwise, it will prompt you to connect to a Perforce server.  Works great with SourceTree.

Comment: Once installed configure as mergetool using: `git config --global merge.tool "p4merge" && git config --global mergetool.p4merge.path "C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4merge.exe"`

Comment: Thanks for pointing open source options here!

Comment: Trying to figure out how to download the windows version of p4merge using your link seems quite a task. There's no clear download link that I can see.

Comment: P4Merge doesn't support --dir-diff, which is a dealbreaker for me

Comment: Link is dead. Updated link: https://www.perforce.com/downloads/visual-merge-tool

Answer (score 27):

I don't know a *good* free tool but [winmerge is ok(ish)](http://winmerge.org/). I've been using the [beyond compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) tools since 1999 and can't rate it enough - it costs about 50 USD and this investment has paid for it self in time savings more than I can possible imagine.

Sometimes tools should be paid for if they are very very good.

Comment: +1 for mentioning paid options.

Comment: winmerge is lousy. The UI makes it hard to tell the left from the right.

Comment: I used WinMerge for years and think it's great. Then I switched to git for version control and needed a GUI for version comparison. First I tried Meld for and found it good, but short of features. Beyond Compare has solved it for me, and I'm quite happy to pay for it.

Answer (score 17):

- TortoiseMerge (part of ToroiseSVN) is **much better** than kdiff3 (I use both and *can compare*);
- p4merge (from Perforce) works also very well;
- Diffuse isn't so bad;
- [Diffmerge from SourceGear](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) *has only one flaw* in handling UTF8-files without BOM, making  in unusable for this case.

Comment: TortoiseGitMerge is actually quite good - I don't know kdiff3, but have never been unhappy or missed anything in TortoiseGitMerge, it lets me do both two and three-way merges very quickly and intuitively.

Comment: @mindplay.dk - TortoiseGitMerge is (mostly) ol' good TortoiseMerge under the hood

Comment: TortoiseMerge doesn't support dir-diff

Answer (score 1):

Another free option is jmeld: http://keeskuip.home.xs4all.nl/jmeld/

It's a java tool and could therefore be used on several platforms.

But (as [Preet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227826/whats-a-good-free-visual-merge-tool-for-git-on-windows/7227954#7227954) mentioned in his answer), *free* is not always the best option. The best diff/merge tool I ever came across is [Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/). Standard edition is available for 99 EUR which is not that much.

They also provide a [documentation](http://www.araxis.com/merge/scm_integration.html#msysGit) for how to integrate Araxis with msysGit.

If you want to stick to a free tool, [JMeld](http://keeskuip.home.xs4all.nl/jmeld/) comes pretty close to Araxis.

Comment: I have heard many good things about Araxis too.

Comment: JMeld moved to https://github.com/MrKuip/JMeld

Answer (score -1):

What's wrong with using Git For Windows? 
From the repo view, there's an icon of the branch you're in (at the top), and if you click on manage you can drag&drop in a very visual and convenient way.

Comment: I think the question was about resolving merge conflicts.