# Force merge file by file - git

Tags: php, git, git-merge

I have just merged two branches 'branch1' and 'branch2'. The problem is that it is now a mess with a lot of conflicts, with sometimes duplicate contents (is it possible ??).

What I want to do is to force for some files from 'branch1' to be merged against 'branch2' and  conversely to force some files from 'branch2' to be merged against 'branch1', knowing I am now on 'branch1'. Is it possible ?

Update : there seems to be problem with git-merge ? Suppose I keep the branch1 version, then

```
echo $this->fetch('prehome.html');
        die;
```

would appear two times, see :

```
protected function prehomepage()
    {
        $var = 'myvar';

        echo $this->fetch('prehome.html');
        die;
    }

<<<<<<< HEAD
    $this->mySmarty->assign('title', 'Primagora');

    echo $this->fetch('prehome.html');
    die;
  }

  /**
   * Generate the campaign block for the general sidebar, called through AJAX.
   */
  protected function getCampaignBlock()
  {
    $from = Utils::fromGet('from');
    echo $this->getCampaignSidebarBlock($from);
    die();
  }
=======
    /**
     * Generate the campaign block for the general sidebar, called through AJAX.
     */
    protected function getCampaignBlock()
    {
        $from = Utils::fromGet('from');
        echo $this->getCampaignSidebarBlock($from);
        die();
    }
>>>>>>> branch2
```

Comment: I always prefer to resolve conflicts rather than force merge. Though you can check [git-merge-file](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-file)

Comment: The problem is that git seems to make mistakes : for example I have method that is in both branches, and now after merging it appears in only one branch, captured inside a === method >>> branch2

Comment: git never remove your code in-spite of you have removed that method & commit in that branch & than you have merge the same in other branch.

Comment: Annotating your source with "conflict markers" to help you resolve conflicts isn't a mistake. It's done deliberately to help you merge.

Comment: @CharlesBailey : I edited my post, there seems to be a problem with git when merging ?

Comment: You may want to try again with the config setting: "merge.conflictstyle=diff3". It may help you understand how the changes have conflicted. That or try a visual 3-way diff tool.

Comment: Looks like somebody changed the number of spaces indenting your code..

Comment: I think that's it, but I don't know how to deal with that unless undoing my merge...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a merge with conflicts (if `git config merge.conflictstyle diff3` is set) , you can:

- ignore that merge and keep your original version (from `branch1`):

```
git show :2:full_path > file
# or 
git checkout-index --stage=2 -- file
```

- ignore that merge and keep the other version (from `branch2`):

```
git show :3:full_path > file
# or 
git checkout-index --stage=3 -- file
```

From there, `git add` and `git commit`.

Answer (score 0):

You should always try to resolve conflicts. They tell you a lot about what is going on.

Netbeans can work with git which makes resolving conflicts a fairly simple task. You can resolve conflicts one by one ore choose the version you want to keep.

What do you mean by duplicate contents? It's not possible to have something marked as change if it's identical in both files.

Comment: @CharlesBailey : I edited my post, there seems to be a problem with git when merging ?

Answer (score 0):

The file you are showing is the intermediate file in an ongoing git merge whit conflicts. The lines from

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
```

to

```
=======
```

is one version and from

```
========
```

to

```
>>>>>branch1
```

is the other. You can then either edit the file by hand and pick the version to use or run a tool to help you resolve the conflicts.
The git command mergetool will guide you in the process of resolving all the conflicts 
https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mergetool.html

```
git mergetool
```

git mergetool will most likely have to be configured to use your favorite conflict resolution program. I have found meld to be very helpful and intuitive.

[Git mergetool with Meld on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821358/git-mergetool-with-meld-on-windows) or
[How to set Meld as git mergetool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956509/how-to-set-meld-as-git-mergetool)