# GIT merge while tryign to merge the ignored files

Tags: git, github, git-svn

I merged some of the files from Branch A to Branch B and later commit-ed on Branch B. Now I need to merge some other file and its not showing in the conflit list or Commit list but while I Compare these two branches I can see the difference in that particular file. What maybe the problem.

Is it because first time I ignored this file and committed the other files?

Please give some input

Comment: Wait a sec. You first **ignored** the file, and now you are wondering why the GIT doesn't do a merge on that file?

Comment: yes because initially i thought I doesn't need it but later point of time I realize I need it

Comment: So simply unignore it now.

Answer (score 0):

While you can [ignore files during a merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232000/git-ignore-files-during-merge), you equally can unignore them, merge again, and [resolve conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15294210/6309).

But remember the [`git svn` caveat](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#_caveats):

> For the sake of simplicity and interoperating with Subversion, it is recommended that all git svn users clone, fetch and dcommit directly from the SVN server, and avoid all git clone/pull/merge/push operations between Git repositories and branches