# Using external diff tool in Gitkraken

Tags: gitkraken

I have installed [Beyond Compare](https://www.scootersoftware.com/index.php) and want to use it as both merge and diff tool inside [Gitkraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/).

[image]

When I select any of the modified files, it still uses the default Gitkraken diff view... I know it *does* say merge tool in the settings, but there must be a way to specify a diff tool too, right?

Comment: linked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667383/configure-a-merge-tool-for-gitkraken-on-windows10

Comment: I have the Lite version of BCompare. And I cannot make it appear in GitKraken. Can you please post your .config files?  
c:\Users\UserName\.gitconfig  AND  
c:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\.gitkraken\config

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now a working feature on GitKraken. On the commit details pane, if you right click on a file, it gives the option of opening in the external tool.

Comment: And you also have the option under General-settings to set a diff-tool!

Answer (score 2):

GitKraken 7.4.0:
`File -> Preferences -> General -> External Diff Tool`

[image: GitKreken with Beyond Compare as a diff tool]

Comment: What do you do if BeyondCompare is not in the drop-down list?

Comment: launch beyond compare, and menu -> install command line tool -> restart Gitkraken

Comment: @SooChunJung - That's only for Mac, and it won't help anyway.

Comment: I will convert my negative vote to positive if you can really show show you got BCompare into that menu. I have GitKraken 9.x and the BCompare is not visible.

Comment: Isn't the screenshot "really" showing it? Not that I care about your vote, just curious... :-)