# git diff is not showing in meld in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ubuntu, meld

I installed `meld` in my `ubuntu 14.04 system`. by following these commands.
In the following `directory path`:

```
anurag@LIBSERV-PC:~$mkdir -p work/crap
anurag@LIBSERV-PC:~$cd work/crap
anurag@LIBSERV-PC:~/work/crap$git clone https://git.gnome.org/browse/meld
anurag@LIBSERV-PC:~/work/crap$cd meld
anurag@LIBSERV-PC:~/work/crap/meld$sudo apt-get install intltool itstool gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 libxml2-utils
anurag@LIBSERV-PC:~/work/crap/meld$sudo python setup.py install
```

It seems installation is done properly. I am working on my `rails project` in the following location:

```
 anurag@LIBSERV-PC:~/vikas/template$ git diff lib/common_methods.rb
```

But in my system `git diff` is not showing in `meld software`.
I am seeing difference on the `terminal` only.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in "[How to set Meld as git mergetool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12957641/6309)", you sill have to declare meld as a difftool

```
git config --global  diff.tool meld
```

Or use [`git difftool --tool=meld`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool).