# Git mergetool will not launch, but difftool will

Tags: git, github, meld, mergetool, difftool

I have conflicts after a merge. To resolve the conflicts, I am trying to use Meld. I don't have any trouble viewing the differences using the difftool. However, when I use the mergetool, Meld will not open.

Git Bash after using the mergetool command:

[image: Git Bash after using the mergetool command]

My gitconfig file is:

```
[merge]
  tool = meld
[mergetool "meld"]
  cmd = \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Meld\\Meld.exe\" "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE" "--output=$MERGED"  
  path = C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/Meld.exe
  trustExitCode = false  
  keepBackup = false

[diff]
  tool = meld
[difftool "meld"]
  cmd = \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Meld\\Meld.exe\" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
  path = C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/Meld.exe

[mergetool]
  keepBackup = false
```

Comment: Try `cmd = 'c:\\...meld.exe' \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE.....`, that is, use single quotes around the path to `meld.exe`, and escape the double quotes around `$LOCAL` and so on.

Comment: Also, I don't use both path and cmd, only cmd, and this works for me (though I use Beyond Compare, not Meld).

Comment: It looks like it’s not launching the mergetool because one of the files was deleted; I think it only launches the external tool if all three versions (base, ours, theirs) exist.

Comment: On a side note, `.pyc` files (whether in `__pycache__` in Python 3 or standalone in Python 2) should never be committed in the first place. (What, never? No, never! What, never? Well... hardly ever!)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Meld as git mergetool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956509/how-to-set-meld-as-git-mergetool)